# underscore.js find objects with same properties

Tags: underscore.js

I'm looking for the best Underscore/JS method that looks at an array of objects and returns true or false if all objects in the collection have a property with the same value.
IE:

this should return true if I check that all 'myprop' is equal.
var myarr = [{ myprop:'123'},{ myprop:'123'},{ myprop:'123'}] .

so, 'myprop' in each collection returns true if each value is the same.

obviously this should return false:
var myarr = [{ myprop:'123'},{ myprop:'357'},{ myprop:'123'}]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please make your formatting readable? I fixed it and you reverted it. -1 until you clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of undescore [every](http://underscorejs.org/#every).

> _.every(list, [predicate], [context]) Alias: all  Returns true if
>   all of the values in the list pass the predicate truth test. Delegates
>   to the native method every, if present.
>
> _.every([true, 1, null, 'yes'], _.identity);
>   => false

```
var myvar1 = [{ myprop:'123'},{ myprop:'123'},{ myprop:'123'}]

_.every(myvar1, function(myvar){return myvar.myprop === '123'});
```

> return true.

```
var myvar2 = [{ myprop:'123'},{ myprop:'357'},{ myprop:'123'}]

_.every(myvar2, function(myvar){return myvar.myprop === '123'});
```

> return false.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hejgdjtp/)**

Comment: thanks! yea i used _.pluck and _.every to make this work. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No quick and dirty function, but if you can guarantee the property exists on all objects:

`_.uniq(_.pluck(myarr, 'myprop')).length == 1`

As djechlin pointed out, the above fails if you can't guarantee the key is present. You could use:

```
var myAttrArr = _.pluck(myarr, 'myprop')
myAttrArr.length == myarr.length && _.uniq(myAttrArr).length == 1
```

You could also use just `every` with some extra logic:

```
var checkVar = myarr['myprop'];
var success = checkVar && _.every(myarr, function(myobj) {
   return myobj['myprop'] === checkVar;
});
```

Comment: just pluck with length  == length of original? what you wrote only checks one has it.

Comment: pluck the attribute, and if there is only one unique they were all the same

Comment: so I was half right. this fails if the prop is missing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Doable in two functions. Use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with `hasOwnProperty` or `has`.